# Keep and patch, or replace white rigid foam during basement remodel?

Tags: insulation, basement, basement-refinishing

I'm removing old wood paneling and drywall which is glued to (what appears to be regular Styrofoam) foam board, which is glued to a cinder block basement wall.  The goal is to add more insulation (2x4 framing + rockwool) to the existing foam board (R10 -> R24).

The issue is that pulling the drywall down is ripping chunks out of the existing foam board - up to 1/2" deep so far - I was hoping to leave in place. The foam should act as vapor barrier, right?

Do I need to patch it somehow (low expanding spray foam?) before installing framing?  Any value in replacing all the old foam with newer product?

[image: white Styrofoam insulation with gouges and glued on drywall]

Comment: I would leave the foam in place it will be better at resisting moisture. I have seen folks put r30 in basement walls the being it would help but since the below grade walls are at a relatively constant temp the additional insulation really did not help. If you wet the pieces that are stuck the Sheetrock will crumble just leaving the paper

Comment: thanks for the tip for crumbling the Sheetrock!

Answer (score 0):

With tears like this, it does not appear to me that this can effectively function as a vapor barrier. I would remove and replace with modern, more dense foam. If your wall is below grade, I would not add 2x4 walls/insulation especially if the only reason for doing so is adding insulation. If you are doing it to add electrical or plumbing, I still would not waste money on rock wool, unless the wall is above grade.

Comment: wall is 1/2 above grade and climate gets pretty cold (Ottawa Canada, and I think 99% design temp is around -13F) I think code is now R20 on basement walls and R24 on above grade walls

Comment: I was thinking of filling the tears with low expanding spray foam and taping all the seams?